# How to run a command asking password in background?

Tags: process, command-line

I want to run a command `sudo apt-get update &`. However after hitting enter, when i hit for `jobs`, it shows the status of these commands as stopped. My guess is that by pushing the process into background I did not provide it an opportunity to ask password. Is there a way to run a process in background which requires a password ?

Answer (score 2):

Try typing `sudo -i` first end then `apt-get update &` or just running the command:

`sudo -i && apt-get update &`

Something else you could try is the command:

`gksudo && sudo apt-get update &`

But I'm not sure if that'll work.

Or you could try adding your user to the list of users that aren't required to enter a password when using sudo.

To do this add type
`sudo visudo` into the terminal. Then add the line

`%super_sudoers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Or whatever you want to call the group (you can change "super_sudoers") and then add your user to that group by typing

`usermod -a -G super_sudoers yourusername` (obviously replacing yourusername with your username)

and reboot (or maybe log out/log in works, not sure) to find you can type suo commands without needing to enter a password. This, of course, means other people can so ensure you always leave your computer locked and don't have automatic login enabled.

Comment: You mean both in separate lines .. ?

Comment: That will mean logging as a root first.. But I would like to avoid it

Comment: your solutions a very risky, I believe

Answer (score 2):

First of All, **"This is not the best practice"**.
 But you can use the command `sudo -S`

**Sudo -S:**
*The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.*

So, Go to the terminal and type:

```
echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -S apt-get update 1>> /home/user/myaptupd.log 2>&1 &
```

it will run the command apt-get update without prompt for a password and backgroud,
and will redirect (append) the stdout and the stderr to a log file in your home named *myaptupd.log*, just in case you can check if everything is allright with the apt-get update command.

Do to this is a large command, you can put this command as an *Alias* in your .bashrc file.
Eg:
In the terminal type:

```
gedit /home/user/.bashrc
```

Add this line to the end of the file

```
alias myaptupd='echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -S apt-get update 1>> /home/user/myaptupd.log 2>&1 &'
```

Reload your .bashrc
In the terminal go to your home directory just type:

```
cd
```

Then type:

```
source .bashrc
```

or

```
. .bashrc
```

Now in the terminal just type the Alias as a command:

```
myaptupd
```

You can check with the command `jobs` the status.

On the other hand you can create a bash script and named myaptupd.sh
Eg:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -S apt-get update 1>> /home/user/myaptupd.log 2>&1 &
```

For security you can set the perms to:

```
chmod 700 /path/to/the/myaptupd.sh
```

Then you can call the script with:

```
 bash /path/to/the/myaptupd.sh
```

Or make an Alias in your .bashrc

```
alias myaptupd='bash /path/to/the/myaptupd.sh'
```

Reload your .bashrc *(like explain it before)* and you can type the name of the alias to run the script:

```
myaptupd
```

Hope this will helpful!

Regards.

Comment: To be explicit on the safety issue: the password will be saved in history, which is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Best and secure way is:

```
su -c "sudo apt-get update &"
```

You can also pipe the output to a log file:

```
su -c "sudo apt-get update > update.log &"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xterm -e "sudo -b nohup php -S localhost:80 -t /media/malcolm/Workspace/sites &>/dev/null"
```

when you close xterm, the php web server still alive,

Don't put "nohup" before "sudo" or else php web server will be killed after closing xterm.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my .bash_profile file.

```
sudobg() {
  sudo echo "Password entered"
  sudo $@ &
}
```

Then I can simply call:

```
prompt$ sudobg echo "Hello from the background."
```

And I get:

```
Password:
Password entered
[1] 6773
prompt$ Hello from the background.
```

Disclaimer: I'm using bash but not Ubuntu. There may be better locations for this function definition.